# Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain in Docker EC2 env

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have dockerized a Java spring-boot(v1.4.2) application which uses Amazon SQS (via spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging v1.1.3 which pulls in aws-java-sdk-sqs v1.11.18). Now to provide the application access to AWS i'm following this pattern:

```
    @Bean
    public AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync() {
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(sourceSqsAccessKey, sourceSqsSecretKey);
        AmazonSQSAsyncClient sqs = new AmazonSQSAsyncClient(credentials);
        sqs.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.fromName(sourceSqsRegion)));

        return new AmazonSQSBufferedAsyncClient(sqs);
    } // WHICH GETS IT CREDS FROM A .yml PROPERTIES FILE
```

*Which usually lets me bypass the exception*: `com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain` *both when running locally and when deploying to my server.*

My problem is this: **when i deploy this service to my server I receive the exception `Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain`** this doesn't happen locally and it doesn't happen to any of my other services deployed to that environment. None are passing the credentials as environment or system variables or anything like that. The only difference is this service uses spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging and the others get the sqs dependency directly.

I also get this error when providing the --env-add AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=some_access --env-add AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=some_secret as environment variables to docker.

Edit see logs below:

```
2017-02-18 08:47:10.408  WARN [application name used to be here...,,,] 1 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.aws.cache.config.annotation.ElastiCacheCachingConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'stackResourceFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration$StackAutoDetectConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.config.StackResourceRegistryFactoryBean]: Factory method 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
2017-02-18 08:47:10.424 ERROR [application name used to be here...,,,] 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.aws.cache.config.annotation.ElastiCacheCachingConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'stackResourceFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration$StackAutoDetectConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.config.StackResourceRegistryFactoryBean]: Factory method 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:478) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:240) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:697) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:526) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at biz.te2.platform.services.delivery.PeoplePickerDeliveryServiceApplication.main(PeoplePickerDeliveryServiceApplication.java:11) [classes!/:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [message-delivery-peoplepicker-core.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [message-delivery-peoplepicker-core.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [message-delivery-peoplepicker-core.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) [message-delivery-peoplepicker-core.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.aws.cache.config.annotation.ElastiCacheCachingConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'stackResourceFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration$StackAutoDetectConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.config.StackResourceRegistryFactoryBean]: Factory method 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:648) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:85) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:249) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:993) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:964) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.aws.cache.config.annotation.ElastiCacheCachingConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'stackResourceFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration$StackAutoDetectConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.config.StackResourceRegistryFactoryBean]: Factory method 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1286) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1255) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1161) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1086) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration$StackAutoDetectConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.config.StackResourceRegistryFactoryBean]: Factory method 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 73 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.config.StackResourceRegistryFactoryBean]: Factory method 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 85 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:131) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.18.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:781) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.18.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:807) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.18.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:702) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.18.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:454) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.18.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:416) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.18.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:365) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.18.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.cloudformation.AmazonCloudFormationClient.doInvoke(AmazonCloudFormationClient.java:1633) ~[aws-java-sdk-cloudformation-1.11.18.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.cloudformation.AmazonCloudFormationClient.invoke(AmazonCloudFormationClient.java:1603) ~[aws-java-sdk-cloudformation-1.11.18.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.cloudformation.AmazonCloudFormationClient.describeStackResources(AmazonCloudFormationClient.java:892) ~[aws-java-sdk-cloudformation-1.11.18.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.config.AutoDetectingStackNameProvider.autoDetectStackName(AutoDetectingStackNameProvider.java:76) ~[spring-cloud-aws-core-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.config.AutoDetectingStackNameProvider.afterPropertiesSet(AutoDetectingStackNameProvider.java:62) ~[spring-cloud-aws-core-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.config.AutoDetectingStackNameProvider.<init>(AutoDetectingStackNameProvider.java:52) ~[spring-cloud-aws-core-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.config.AutoDetectingStackNameProvider.<init>(AutoDetectingStackNameProvider.java:56) ~[spring-cloud-aws-core-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextStackAutoConfiguration$StackAutoDetectConfiguration.stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean(ContextStackAutoConfiguration.java:71) ~[spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextStackAutoConfiguration$StackAutoDetectConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bbb47f74.CGLIB$stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean$0(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextStackAutoConfiguration$StackAutoDetectConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bbb47f74$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f7d4da5e.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextStackAutoConfiguration$StackAutoDetectConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bbb47f74.stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 86 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

disabled ContextStackAutoConfiguration
by updating my @SpringBootApplication as follows: `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class)`

Answer (score 0):

You code seems correct but it would nice to look at the complete class and the stack trace to make sure the exception is indeed originated when instantiating the client. It is possible that some other client is being created under the hood that requires credentials. I do have some suggestions for your deployed environment though.

You should be using EC2 instance profiles or ECR task roles (if you are using ECR) for access to AWS. Passing credentials directly to code is a security risk and should be avoided in production. Only use credentials if trying to access cross-account resources. Assuming foreign IAM roles is also preferred.

Comment: thanks for your reply. if some other client was being created under the hood" then it would show as an issue in my local environment too. This is a pretty light application less than 450 total lines including all .java, .xml, & .yml files so the room for surprises is pretty low i would say

Comment: It seems that 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' was failing to initialize. Upon inspecting the [source code](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/blob/master/spring-cloud-aws-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/aws/core/env/stack/config/StackResourceRegistryFactoryBean.java), I found that it accepts a CloudFormation client in the constructor which is probably failing to create because of missing credentials.